# How to make a "messagebox.askquestion" using array variables

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to use the index and combining the `x` and `y` arrays so that they correspond. However, they don't seem to be working.

```
from tkinter import *    
from tkinter import messagebox

x = ['screen','speakers','earphone jack','button','switch off','storage']    
y = ['is the screen cracked','have the speakers been in conatct with water','has the earphone jack been in contact with water','is your button broken','is your battery older than 2 years','have you deleted enough data to allow more space']

solutions = ['go to the nearest phone store and get direct help','change your screen','put your phone in uncooked rice overnight and check in the morning','change your phone battery','delete enough data to allow you to download whatever you need']

**def problem1_1():**    
    i =  ' '.join(x)
    i.split(' ')
    p = problem1.get()
    if p == x[0] :
        messagebox.askquestion(title = "screen", messsage =y[x.index(0)])
        return**

myGui = Tk()    
problem1 = StringVar()    
myGui.geometry("500x500+200+200")   
myGui.title("troubleshooting system")  
myheader1 = Label(text = "Welcome To the Phone Troubleshooting System").pack()    
header2 = Label(text = "What seems to be the issue with  your phone? Is it an issue with your : screen, speakers, button,earphone jack, battery or storage",fg = 'blue',bg = 'yellow').pack()   
ientry = Entry(textvariable = problem1).pack()    
OkButton = Button(text = 'OK', command = problem1_1).pack()    
myGui.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you copy the code into your question you will likely get a faster answer

Comment: Please include the code as text in the question itself rather than just linking to a picture of it.

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` statement's logic is flawed right now.

Instead of index of 0, you'd like to get index of the input.

```
p = problem1.get().lower() 
y[x.index(p)]
```

And instead of comparing the first item of `x`, you should check if `x` contains user's input.

```
if p in x:
```

Additionally there is a typo in your `askquestion` line. Option `message` spelled with two `s` not three.